# О непозволительной математике

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тематика

Мне кажется, что программирования без математики не бывает, так что, может быть, не следует так строго рубить все математические вопросы?

Не буду говорить, что надо менять тематику сайта, но мне все же кажется, что к математическим вопросам надо относиться как минимум без излишней жестокости. В конце концов, представим, что вопрос предваряет *"дали задание написать программу, моделирующую ..., а потому"* - и вопрос практически мгновенно проходит через фильтр тематики.

Comment: На мой взгляд, если автор вопроса указывает, что решение математической задачи ему необходимо для нужд, так или иначе связанных с программированием, и поясняет, каким именно образом, то вопрос оставлять. В противном случае даже удалять, а не закрывать, а вопрошающему предложить [соответствующий сайт](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). [Этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521613/199934) удалил бы.

Comment: однако есть тэг алгоритм и под него почти все математические вопросы подходят.

Comment: @СашаЧерных При том, что в реальной жизни я даже подрабатываю переводчиком с английского :), скажу откровенно - на англоязычные форумы меня затянуть можно только тогда, когда все остальные способы не работают. Если бы был такой же русскоязычный вариант...

Comment: @Harry, конечно. А если что и стоит удалять, так это некоторых участников, любящих удалять все остальное.

Comment: Зря удалили [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521613/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD), о котором шла речь, пока не закончилось это обсуждение. Чтобы другие участники лучше понимали, о чём шла речь.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Дело не в конкретном вопросе, а в принципе, в отношении к математическим вопросам - они резулярно если и не закрываются, то минусуются как оффтопик. Если мы сведем дискуссию о принципиальном вопросе к обсасыванию одного конкретного вопроса - то воз останется на месте...

Comment: Если вы предлагаете расширение онтопика, укажите, **какие в точности** математические вопросы вы предлагаете считать онтопиком. Например: «как доказать, что существует всего 5 правильных многогранников?» на мой взгляд не должно быть разрешено.

Comment: @VladD Ну, я думаю, что такой вопрос останется попросту безответным. Что, кстати, приводит ко второй мысли, которую я пока не выносил на обсуждение - убирать вопросы, которые в течение, скажем, пары месяцев остаются не отвеченными.

Comment: @Harry: Окей, давайте тогда попробуем всё же найти границы разумного. Контрпредложение: почему бы тогда не разрешить и вопросы по физике? Пусть тоже остаются без ответа. Зачем вообще тогда на сайте есть онтопик?

Comment: @VladD Как я понимаю, сделать несколько русскоязычных сайтов - задача слишком сложная, потому и предлагал несколько расширить рамки. С другой стороны, как говорится - "наше дело - предложить, ваше - отказаться" :), так что я ни на чем не настаиваю, и выносил этот вопрос для обсуждения. Нет так нет.

Comment: @Harry: Я не представитель администрации, а просто один из участников, так что моё мнение не может быть окончательным решением. Но я хотел выяснить границы вашего предложения. Я правильно понимаю, что вы предлагаете разрешить _любые_ вопросы по математике, и просто допустить, что на некоторые не будет ответа?

Answer (score 22):

Лайфхак:

- математический вопрос можно завуалировать под гольф, получить -20, но вопрос не удалят и напишут кучу ответов.
- можно поискать олимпиадную задачку или задачку с егэ, или по крайней мере попытаться сформулировать ее также неожиданно. Особенно хорошо идут задачки на суммы арифметической прогрессии и системы счисления.
- геометрические задачки легко трансформируются в вопросы по opengl (в удаленном вопросе надо было просто сказать про текстурки какие-нить, которые на ту сферу натягивать надо), на плоскости - по css&html&js.
- задачки по теорверу отлично идут, главное упомянуть `random`. или в случае БД `order by rand()`.
- использование матаппарата в алгоритмах и оптимизации, тут как бы XY-проблема, но ответы будут наверняка...

ЗЫ :)

Comment: Да, был бы правильный контекст к таким вопросам.

Comment: Не понимаю цель вашего ответа. Вы считаете ваши предложения улучшат сайт?

Comment: @jfs Это намек на двойные стандарты в модерировании вопросов. Можно задать любой вопрос по любой тематике, сформулировав его так, чтоб он подходил под онтопик. У меня есть куча ответов на вопросы, сформулированные как в этом ответе. По факту вопросы математические.

Comment: Вы хотите больше таких вопросов или меньше?

Comment: @jfs меня, как отвечающего, интересуют любые вопросы, на которые я могу ответить. если у математика плохо с программированием или у программиста плохо с математикой, то почему бы не помочь. Формулировка - атрибут вопроса, но не суть.

Comment: @YuraIvanov О, мой последователь в написании "неправильных ответов" на Мете! =)

Comment: @YuraIvanov: согласен с вашим последним комментарием. Почему вы эту идею в ответе не отразили вместо описания попыток обмануть участников отвечающих на вопросы (нас с вами)?