# Вопросы по математике оставлять нельзя закрывать

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Чистая [математика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0):

```
всего вопросов: 677
из них открытых: 590
из них имеют ответы: 516
```

В каком месте заголовка поставить запятую? Быть или не быть вопросам по математике на этом сайте?

---

Связанные вопросы:

- [О непозволительной математике](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3030/178576)
- [Почему нету сообщества "математика на русском"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7423/178576)
- [Что случилось с сайтом "∞ Математика"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7700/178576)

Comment: Что здесь значит "чистая математика"? Я думал, это когда только одна единственная метка, но получил всего лишь [64 таких вопроса](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/975544?Tag=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: _запятую?_ - [Рекомендуемые написания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Казнить_нельзя_помиловать) "Казнить: нельзя помиловать" и "Казнить нельзя — помиловать". Даёшь вопросы по грамматике!

Comment: @älёxölüt, подразумевалось: «статистика по метке». в первоначальной редакции вопроса стояла другая цитата (сейчас она — в одном из ответов), в которой упоминалась «чистая математика». потом цитату заменил, а фраза так и осталась.

Comment: Можете привести примеры вопросов с этой меткой, которые сейчас являются оффтопиком, и которые предлагается разрешить?

Comment: @PashaPash, это мне вопрос? я не интересуюсь темой «математика», а вопрос поднял в связи с тем, что в очередях проверки время от времени попадаются вопросы с этой меткой, и как с ними быть, непонятно: вроде бы как и офтоп, но в то же время есть множество открытых и даже с ответами.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вопросы по чистой (не имеющей отношения к программированию) математике вроде бы редко встречаются. Судя по  запросу älёxölüt - меньше 30 штук за прошлый год. Я прошелся по топу - они почти все или закрыты, или более-менее имеют отношения к программированию. Поэтому и пытаюсь понять, за что там ниже участники голосуют :)

Comment: Igor'а на вас нет.

Comment: тематика математики :-D

Answer (score 42):

> Математика — царица наук.
>   *Карл Фридрих Гаусс*
>
> Все искусства тяготеют к музыке; все науки – к математике.
>   *Джордж Сантаяна*

вопросам — быть

Comment: Подразумеваются вопросы любой сложности? Начиная с "как решить квадратное уравнение?"

Comment: @PashaPash, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы ([tag:сарказм])

Comment: Сарказм из очереди проверки :) Это бы скорее призыв подумать к голосующим, чем вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash а в чём разница по сравнению с вопросами "как вывести Hello world"?

Comment: @Suvitruf хотя в том, что почти всем разработчикам более-менее регулярно приходится этот Hello world выводить, хотя бы при изучении нового языка. А вот квадратные уравнения мне давно уже решать не приходилось. Хотя, в геймдеве чистой математики больше, так что может быть вам она чаще встречается.

Comment: @PashaPash у меня неоднозначное мнение по треду вообще. Я за матан, но если, всё же, он нужен для прикладной задачи (game-dev и т.п), но т.к. нету ru аналога для матана в сети SE, то может стоить и общие матан вопросы позволить.

Comment: @Suvitruf матан для прикладной задачи и сейчас онтопик. а тред - по разрешению всего матана вообще.

Comment: @PashaPash, вопрос был задан для прояснения неясной (по крайней мере для меня) ситуации с «математическими» вопросами. я лично склоняюсь к тому, что это «офтопик». вот только аргументировать это не смогу. если у вас есть аргументы — напишите, пожалуйста, ещё один ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно отдельный тред для обсуждения создать; этот вопрос, всё же, как голосовалка.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin поздно обсуждать, уже наголосовали. теперь остается только выяснить, за что именно :(

Comment: сайт [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) является вторым по по количеству вопросов после основного Stack Overflow (для сравнения ru.SO на 6-ом месте). Нового сайта на русском не будет (в ближайшие годы), поэтому вопрос: станет ли рунет лучше, если вопросы по математике на движке SO в рамка ru.SO можно будет задавать? Есть плюсы и минусы. На мой взгляд плюсы перевешивают (если целью считать основную миссию SO: чтобы каждому не приходилось с нуля задачи решать, чтобы можно было расти отталкиваясь от существующих решений)

Answer (score 2):

Больше полезных знаний — лучше: интуитивно кажется, что вопросы по математике и уместны, и интересны на нашем сайте одновременно. Но! Случается, что мы подразумеваем одно, говоря «математика», а другие люди понимают тот же самый термин иначе. На мой взгляд, чтобы принять взвешенное решение, стоит собрать несколько десятков вопросов, которые бы вы хотели видеть на сайте, и далее проголосовать за/против них всем сообществом (аналогично [Зоне 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)).

Математика бывает очень разной: от школьной программы, до высшей математики в технических ВУЗах, от теоретических доказательств теорем, до прикладных тем вроде булевой алгебры. К слову, в сети Stack Exchange есть два сайта математики и они очень разные.

Кроме того, стоит помнить, что чтобы все вопросы по математике отображались корректно, нам будет необходимо добавить MathJax. MathJax — это  сторонняя JS-библиотека, код которой исполняется на клиенте. И грузить ее придется всегда и всем! (Кроме того, на сколько я помню, раньше в разметке MathJax и Markdown были конфликты.)

Математика — замечательная наука, которая с каждым днем становится все ближе и ближе к программистам (машинное обучение, анализ данных, прикладная статистика и тд). Мне самому очень интересны многие из этих тем. Необходимо очень четко провести границу, что допустимо на сайте, а что — нет, исходя из имеющихся технических возможностей (например, мы вряд ли добавим поддержку MathJax) и интересов участников сообщества (например, думаю, машинное обучение будет интересно многим, а вот решения квадратных уравнений, вероятно, единицам).

Чтобы понимать, как выглядит математика в вопросах и ответах, пожалуйста, посмотрите на сайте [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/), оставшийся от «Сети Знаний».

Comment: [да уж](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/172105), «математика» в вопросах и ответах.

Answer (score -13):

> Выпьем за то, чтобы чистая математика всегда оставалась совершенно бесполезной!
> *Приписывается Генри Джону Смиту*
>
> Математика и техника живут в полнейшем согласии и будут жить так и впредь, потому что между ними нет ничего общего.
> *Приписывается Давиду Гильберту*

вопросам — не быть (закрывать с формулировкой «офтопик»).

о чём и написать ясно и недвусмысленно в описании метки [математика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Согласен, ведь мы - сообщество программистов, а не математиков.