# Расширение тематики - Математика

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

В недавнем голосовании [Вопросы по математике оставлять нельзя закрывать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8683/) с большим 
отрывом победил пункт "вопросам — быть".

Математические вопросы, хотя бы немного связанные с разработкой ПО, сейчас - онтопик.

Чистая же математика, в отличие от железа, code golf и остальных расширений онтопика в прошлом, выходит за [рамки общей темы сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов.

Я вижу несколько организационных проблем:

- Вопросы по чистой математике у нас бывают достаточно редко. Вопросов [единичной меткой "математика" всего 166](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/980751?Tag=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), считая удаленные. Из них 45 заданы за последний год. IMO, это достаточно мало для того, чтобы так значительно расширять онтопик.
- У hashcode.ru, с которого в свое время переехал ru.stackoverflow.com, остался математический подраздел - [math.hashcode.ru](http://math.hashcode.ru), который до сих пор жив. Там 38 тысяч вопросов и свой community. Мы будем с ними конкурировать? Предложим им влиться в ruSO вместе с контентом? Вольем волевым решением?
- Какой уровень вопросов ожидается? Математика - обширная тема. В англоязычном сегменте сейчас есть разделение на:

  - [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) - Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields
  - [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) - site for professional mathematicians
  - [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)
  - [Computational Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
  - и еще пару сайтов поменьше....

Мы хотим сразу всю математику? От уровня "помогите с домашкой для 5-го класса" до рецензирования диссертаций? Или хочется видеть что-то уровня Mathematics, как самого востребованного сегмента?

Предлагаю провести оценку новой темы по тем же принципам, которые используются на Зоне 51:

- Ради сбора материала - объявить математику временным онтопиком.
- Собрать хотя бы десяток существующих вопросов по математике, которые хотелось бы видеть на сайте, но которые сейчас подлежат закрытию как оффтопик.
- На основе собранного - уточнить предлагаемый онтопик так, чтобы определение можно было вписать в справку. "Вопросы по математике - разрешены" - слишком размыто.

Comment: А зачем удалённые в статистику приводить? Чтобы показать, что даже с удалёнными (по причине возможной оффтопичности) выходит капля в море?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ раз математика была оффтопиком - вопросы могли закрываться и убиваться духом через месяц. Просто хотел сэкономить время тем, кто решил бы посчитать "и удаленные" тоже, и заодно не попасть в ситуацию "их мало, потому что мы всех их снесли как оффтоп".

Comment: Наверное все таки чистую математику не стоит вливать в сайт. Как уже писали, есть mathematics, а для тех, кто не знает английский - математика на хэшкоде(вполне рабочая кстати). Для школьных заданий есть znanija и otvet.mail.ru

Comment: может предложить ru.math.stackexchange.com  на area51.... думаю многие поддержат

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev насколько я знаю, [они (временно?) не принимают не-англоязычные предложения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53004/248633). Иначе Николас давно бы переселил математику с хэшкода. Можно попробовать пропихнуть, но шанс достаточно мал :(

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev там сейчас даже англоязычные сайты то сложно протолкнуть, т.к. часто инициатива закрывается как офтопик, чего уж про локализованные сайты говорить.