# Что не так с вопросом про "Пересечение сферы и треугольника"?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Что не так с этим вопросом?

[Пересечение сферы и треугольника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110163/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1915060_1110163).

В нём мало текста?

Даже в его первой редакции - всё понятно и конкретно.
Чисто математическая проблема. Лаконичная формулировка.
Это эталонный вопрос, такие надо в пример приводить, а не закрывать.

Имхо, намного хуже, если в вопросе - простыня, которую нужно долго и вдумчиво читать, чтобы понять в чём же, собственно, вопрос.

Comment: Я точно знаю, что у нас есть те, кто не признают математические вопросы. Они ли голосовали за закрытие, не знаю)

Comment: я знаю как узнать, но не буду =)

Comment: Но в данном случае, думаю, закрывают как "домашку".

Comment: Это возмутительно, имхо как раз в ответах на такие вопросы ценность этого ресурса

Comment: Я о том же говорил, когда обсуждали эту причину закрытия =/

Comment: В очереди проверок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/464433

Answer (score 9):

Вижу всего два варианта:

1. Либо людям не нравится математика (а она у нас, кстати, [разрешена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8683/15479)).
2. Либо закрывают как [домашки](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Сам вопрос занятный и полезный для базы знаний, как по мне. Когда было обсуждение "домашек", то я такие вопросы приводил в пример того, что их закрывать не надо.

Comment: Домашка-не домашка, по мне так нет разницы, каждая домашка - если это не дубликат может быть так же полезна как и любой другой вопрос, мало ли кто интересуется банальщиной для вас.

Comment: Хотя вопрос далеко не банальный, я уверен что единицы пользователей, могут что-то толковое сами на него ответить.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ может. Жаль, что не все это понимают. Много интересных вопросов было из-за этого закрыто.

Comment: Есть ли возможность отслеживания таких закрывальщиков с последующими санкциями?

Comment: @avp а какие санкции могут быть?

Comment: Бан на закрывание?

Comment: @avp модераторы такое делать не могут. Баны на закрывание только автоматика выписывает.

Comment: И какие события подвигают ее на такой бан?

Comment: @avp если много проверок в очереди зафейлить. Но даже это работает только на новичках. Те, кто уже тысячи проверок сделал, никогда не будут забанен в очередях. Баракин, к примеру, специально **все** проверки проваливает, но бана всё ещё нет)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Можно "Это сообщение касается вашей учетной записи на Stack Overflow на Русском" и суспеншен.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik А Баракин правда все проверки неправильно делает?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica формально они правил никаких не нарушают.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica да, нарочно проваливает)