# Закрыт (с многократным подтверждением решения) достойный вопрос по численным методам

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, причины-закрытия, переоткрытие-вопросов

Недавний вопрос ["Какой алгоритм лучше всего использовать для матрицы в примере"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198802/337980) был закрыт с формулировкой:

> Закрыт. Этот вопрос [не по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Ответы на него в данный момент не принимаются.

Такое решение мне непонятно по следующим причинам:

1. [Вопросы по математике](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8683/337980) — по теме. Тем более, на мой взгляд, вопросы **по алгоритмам** линейной алгебры и численным методам.
2. Закрытый вопрос — абсолютно конкретен. Несмотря на то, что он идет с формулировкой "*лучше всего*", на этот вопрос в определенной степени можно ответить в области численных методов. Определенная степень — указание семейств методов и их конкретных аспектов. Большая часть вопроса заключается в определении типа и подтипа матрицы, поэтому гуглить тут непросто, кроме того, существует расхождение в терминологии между англоязычной и русскоязычной литературой.
3. Домашнее задание? Ну, теоретически и практически — возможно. Но данный вопрос с определенными модификациями возникал у меня несколько лет назад вне решения каких-то работ в университете.

---

Поэтому **я не понимаю причины закрытия** данного вопроса (ну **небольшое косметическое** редактирование ему не повредит, конечно) и вопрошаю к его переоткрытию.

---

Вопрос три раза попадал в очереди проверок:

1. [Очередь первых сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/536480) — успешно пройдя, хотя минимальное редактирование могло быть сделано уже в этот момент.
2. [Очередь некачественных постов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/536484) — с **единогласием 7 участников** по закрытию вопроса.
3. [Очередь на перетоткрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/536601) — с **единогласием 3 участников** оставить вопрос закрытым.

Что-то странное происходит в очередях проверок. Или я чего-то не понимаю? Чем оправдано такое решение проверяющих?

NB: Я являюсь автором одного из ответов к вопросу.

Comment: Хорошо, что вы обратили внимание на такой вопрос (в результате справедливость восторжествовала). Что касается  --  *`"Чем оправдано такое решение проверяющих?"`*, то очевидно, что тут многовато некомпетентных участников, которые сами этого не осознают. Как следствие, надо думать о том, как в принципе изменить подход к закрытию вопосов. Например, ничего (кроме откровенного бреда) не закрывать.

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле так себе, очень размытый. "Какой алгоритм использовать для решения системы с матрицей коэффициентов". Стоило бы в него включить больше подробностей и описания задачи и условий.

Answer (score 3):

А что хорошего в том вопросе? Чем он отличается от сотен других домашек? Автор просто скинул задачу и решайте как хотите - мы теперь не база вопросов/ответов, а решебник для студентов?
То, что вы можете дать четкий ответ на вопрос не делает вопрос качественным. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1203366/179763) другой вопрос, давайте его тоже заплюсуем, чем он хуже то?

Я понимаю, если вы знаете хорошо тему вопроса и хотите поделиться с нами своими знаниями - это здорово (без сарказма), я только за. Я сам иногда решаю домашки, если мне хочется покодить алгоритмы или освежить с памяти C#. Но это не делает вопрос хорошим.

Потому лично я прекрасно понимаю, почему вопрос закрыли. Автор вопроса не сделал самостоятельно ничего. Он даже картинку в текст не перевел а скинул, что ему захотелось скинуть, и галочку поставил на ответе, что ему понравился. Он не ответил ни на один вопрос. Мы теперь такое отношение к отвечающим поощряем?

Я считаю, что то, что вы понимаете задание и можете дать ответ не значит, что вопрос хороший. Если масштабировать такие вопросы, то мы превратимся просто в решебники задачек.

Я к тому, что я приветсвую тех, кто делится знаниями даже в таких вопросах. Но при этом я вполне понимаю, почему подобные вопросы закрывают.

Comment: Перевести картинку с формулой в текст? Странно. Насколько я знаю, на SO.Ru нет поддержки MathJax. Без него, картинка предпочтительнее текста для формул.

Comment: Этот вопрос может быть домашкой, а может и не быть. Это серьезная научная проблема и вопрос точно может быть и от студента старших курсов, а скорее - магистратуры\аспирантуры. Я не знаю как человек может задать этот вопрос лучше.

Comment: Также я не очень понимаю на какой вопрос человек должен был ответить. Все вопросы кроме первого появились после принятого ответа. Лично я против решения домашек за людей. Но не в случае, когда домашковость задачи вообще неочевидна, и это конкретно тяжелый и активный исследовательский вопрос.

Comment: Если этот вопрос был бы задан в данной форме на [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), к нему не было бы претензий (за исключением форматирования). Я понимаю, что сообщества разные и с разными правилами. Но как-то я не вижу чему данный вопрос будет противоречить даже здесь, тем более с закрытием по формулировке "не по теме".

Comment: пример [вопроса с матрицей текстом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198516/179763), но это даже не обязательно было делать, но хотя бы как то отреагировать стоило, нет?

Comment: На мой взгляд, матрица-текстом для математического вопроса выглядит отвратительно. Либо MathJax, либо картинка.

Comment: вопрос может быть от кого угодно. Но что этот студент сделал сам, чтобы найти результат? У нас тут каждый второй вопрос, где просто кидают задания и просят сделать за них

Comment: Человек должен был показать свои исследования вопроса. Что он пытался. что не получилось, какие проблемы возникли.

Comment: Здесь спрашивают о методе. Не спрашивают о том как это запрограммировать. На такие вопросы приятно отвечать.

Comment: То есть если бы он сказал, что пробовал LU декомпозицию, но это неэффективно - то вас бы это устроило?

Comment: я и не говорил о программировании. Не обязательно программировать, чтобы показать, что сам что то пытался.

Comment: Меня бы устроил подробный вопрос, что конкретно автор делал, чтобы найти ответ на него. Поглядите на любой из моих вопросов, там есть такая информация.

Comment: У нас с вами разные критерии качества вопроса. Возможно моя перспектива как эксперта по этой тематике искажает мое восприятие. Я вас услышал, но в данном случае конкретно не согласен.

Comment: Мне кажется, не надо быть экспертом, чтобы увидеть некачественный вопрос. Я не умаляю ваши заслуги, но вы по сути отстаиваете что просто скинутое чье то задание является хорошим вопросом, с чем я не согласен. Не верите мне - просто почитайте первый же параграф [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как мы видим, между двумя квалифицированными людьми с большим опытом на StackExchange есть серьезное расхождение в этом. Значит, как минмум, не все так однозначно.

Comment: Лично я голосовал за закрытие сотен подобных вопросов, но с другой причиной (см про учебные задания). Ваша точка зрения ясна,моя тоже ясна. Для меня все однозначно. В смысле, у меня нет сомнений в моей позиции. Все мои доводы в моем ответе / комментариях.

Comment: Говоря про приемлемый вопрос, я бы хотел видеть что то [типа такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768072/179763), с перечислением рассмотренных вариантов, плюсами, минусами и прочим. Такому вопросу я бы даже + поставил.

Answer (score 1):

Представьте себе идентичный вопрос (текст дословен):

> Каким алгоритмом лучше всего пользоваться для данной геометрической задачки?
>
> Какой алгоритм поиска решения (А, В ..) можно использовать для системы с кругами как на приведенной картинке?
>
> [картинка с пересечением N кругов и M линией]

Разве он будет хорош? Нет.
Если таких вопросов будет задано 5, 10, 50, с различающимися картинками, но идентичным текстом, как вы будете между ними ориентироваться? Никак.
Как этот вопрос можно будет найти из поисковика? Никак.

У хорошего вопроса должно быть описание, и оно должно быть читаемо и индексируемо, а картинка - лишь дополнение.

Как улучшить вопрос о котором идет речь - дополнитеть текст описанием матрицы, предметной областью, решаемой задачей.

Comment: Я не спорю, что словесное описание матрицы коэффициентов вопросу не повредит, но плохая индексируемость вопроса поисковиками не значит, что вопрос нужно закрыть. И повторяя свое прошлый сообщение: «(2) Зачем в вопросе информация о предметной области и решаемой задаче, если вопрос о численных методах»?

Comment: @eanmos а давайте чуть-чуть усугубим и все вопросы будем называть "Есть вопрос", а все содержимое постить картинками ;-) Хорошо же получится! Дополнительная информация в вопросе нужна, чтобы его было проще найти. Вот я решаю задачу, но не знаю, что это называется "численный метод", так у меня хотя бы будет шанс найти по описанию.

Comment: Еще раз, я абсолютно с вами согласен, что вопросу не повредит словесное описание матрицы коэффициентов. Но разве вы считаете, что плохая индексируемость — повод закрывать вопрос?

Comment: @eanmos я с вами не согласен, вопросу не *"не повредит"*, а ***"необходимо"*** словесное описание (уж коль скоро все наши поисковые технологии оперируют текстом). Стоит ли закрывать неиндексируемый вопрос - скорее да. До получения ответа - это стимул ТС вопрос улучшить, а после получения ответа - он все равно бесполезен для Базы Знаний. Закрытый вопрос можно отредактировать и переоткрыть.

Comment: Ответ тоже используется для индексирования поисковиков. По запросу [как решить циклическую трехдиагональную систему](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E+%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83) у меня этот пост сейчас на второй странице гугла.

Comment: @AntonMenshov согласитесь, как хорошо что хотя бы в ответе это описание дали! ) Только это что значит - что скорее ответы хорошие, а не вопрос ))

Comment: Потому что это - была скрытая часть вопроса, которая неизвестна автору. "Хотя бы" - это странный оборот, без этого ответа на вопрос не было бы. Заметим, что ОБА ОТВЕТА сразу же это упоминают в первых строчках.

Comment: @AntonMenshov ну вот, какие хорошие ответы. Не будем их закрывать ;-)

Comment: ну вот какие отличные ревьюеры в очередях, не будем их банить. :-)

Comment: @Kromster, «стоит ли закрывать неиндексируемый вопрос - скорее да», ну, у закрытия есть ряд причин, которые описаны в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), и причины «плохая индексируемость» там нет. Поэтому, закрывать вопрос просто потому что он плохо индексируется все-таки не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с автором вопроса, часто к сожалению так происходит, что вопросы подвергаются усиленной цензуре со стороны людей, который не совсем компетентны.

Можно вспомнить вопрос [Будет ли async await в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183831/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-async-await-%d0%b2-java)
, который и закрывался и минусовался и чего только с ним и не делали - в итоге мы совместно с автором "вытянули" его из пучины забвения и минусов.

Стараюсь в тегах [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) следить за тем, чтобы укрощать зарвавшихся поборников псевдочистоты, за остальные теги не скажу - не хватает сил (и самое главное компетенции)

Comment: "Будет ли async await в Java?" — "а изобретут ли машину времени?", "я вот ща кину кости, у меня выпадет 12?", "что выведет `Math.random()`?" etc.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor выпадет с вероятностью 1/12; число в диапазоне [0.0, 1.0). А про машину времени надо подумать...