# Перестаньте закрывать все подряд

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, причины-закрытия, переоткрытие-вопросов

Давно уже начал замечать, что у нас закрываются многие абсолютно нормальные вопросы. Причем причина закрытия берется откуда-то с потолка.

---

Вчера наткнулся на [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205660) — закрыт с причиной

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?»)
> должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и
> минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в вопросе просьба «помочь с отладкой»?

Да, этот вопрос простой. Да, автор просто спрашивает аналоги инструкции `dec r`, но это не значит что вопрос плохой — он конкретен, понятен и полезен для других. Конечно, ответ можно легко найти в гугле, но мы же строим базу знаний, да?

---

Да дело даже не в этом конкретном вопросе. Эту проблему заметил не только я — вот [ссылка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10994/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82) на недавнее обсуждение по поводу закрытия вопроса по численным методам. Предлагаю обсудить причину проблемы и ее решение.

Comment: А чем вопрос об аналогах dec отличается, скажем, от вопроса [об аналогах abs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1201761/176064)? Этот вопрос не просто прост. Он тривиален. И бесполезен, как для архива базы знаний,так и для участников. Лучший ответ — `sub r, 1`. Покажите мне человека, который занимается ассемблером, знает dec, но не знает add/sub..

Comment: @vp_arth Формального то повода нет. Можно минуснуть, но закрывать не за что, "слишком тривиален" это не причина закрытия. А по способам вычисления модуля кстати вопрос даже хороший, зря закрыли. Про знаковый бит то не все знают.

Comment: @vp_arth, поддержу WhiteKnight в том, что вопрос об аналогах `abs` совсем не тривиален (надо знать хотя бы на базовом уровне IEEE-754, если числа целые, то two's complement и т. д.). Но этот вопрос плох тем, что его необходимо конкретизировать и нормально сформулировать, поэтому он закрыт правильно (ИМХО, конечно).

Comment: @vp_arth, т. е. если вопрос прост (тривиален), то он бесполезен для базы знаний?

Comment: Вопрос о том, как сложить 2 числа, да, бесполезен) Это о простых. abs без встроенной функции, не просто бесполезен, а и вреден. Нужно пользоваться встроенными функциями =)

Comment: @vp_arth, вот видите, вы бы лучше ответили автору вопроса как написать свой `abs` для разных типов, а потом большими буквами написали, что нужно пользоваться встроенными функциями. Тогда все, кто до сих пор писали свою `abs` увидели бы ваш ответ и стали пользоваться встроенной функций. А вы говорите, пользы нет)

Comment: @vp_arth Пользоваться то нужно, но знать детали все равно часто необходимо. У нас то сайт для разных разработчиков, в том числе кто потенциально будет писать свои компиляторы или библиотеки. Так что насчет вредности я не согласен.

Comment: Вот послушаю вас, заведу аккаунт и начну шерстить мануалы и построчно переносить в вопросы на ruSO =)

Comment: @vp_arth, а вам не кажется, что в вопросе про `abs()` как раз вскрывается **концептуальная ошибка** со встроенной функцией? Может правильней было бы возвращать из нее *unsigned*?

Comment: @eanmos Так для численных методов и математики  есть отдельный сайт https://math.stackexchange.com/ А по вопросам халявщиков давно пытаются найти решение. Пока лучшее — тревога о домашках, которую явно стоит переработать.

Comment: @avp, менять тип не очень хорошая идея) Вы же не требуете, чтобы floor(float) возвращал int?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, 1) math.stackexchange.com на английском языке и численные методы там — оффтопик. К тому же, наш SO прекрасно подходит для вопросов по численным методам, ибо это про программирование. 2) С чего вы взяли, что автор вопроса — халявщик? Что, собственно, он должен был сделать сам, если он просто просит эффективный алгоритм для решения СЛАУ со специфичной матрицей коэффициентов?

Comment: Проблема в том, что некоторые пользователи считают ruSO ресурсом где за тебя сделают всю работу еще и бесплатно. Новички даже не пытаются разобраться с задачей, вот собственно "Если можно, то несколько способов.". А какие человек сам попытался найти способы?! Что он сделал и что не получилось? И как раз на легкие вопросы можно поискать ответ, наверняка и дубликат уже можно найти (не говорю об этом вопросе, но на большинство других). На so пусть попробуют задавать подобные вопросы!

Comment: @HamSter, не кажется ли вам, что негативное отношение к «халявщикам» не должно являться поводом к закрытию вопроса?

Comment: @eanmos дело в том, что халявство ТС очень сильно кореллирует с низким качеством задаваемых вопросов и обратно - с их полезностью кому-либо в будущем.

Comment: @eanmos, " негативное отношение к «халявщикам»" и вызвано качеством, пользой вопроса. На SO такие вопросы, в основном, не проходят их сразу же закрывают без дискуссий.

Comment: @HamSter, вопрос от «халявщика» и плохой вопрос — это ортогональные понятия. Я вижу проблему в том, что закрываются *неплохие* вопросы в независимости о того, «халявные» они или нет. Если вопрос низкого качества, его, очевидно, нужно закрыть, тут спору нет.

Comment: *"Перестаньте закрывать все подряд"* - перестаньте обобщать все подряд

Comment: @Kromster, это вы мне? Не помню, чтобы я обобщал все подряд. Что вы имеет в виду?

Answer (score 14):

В чем я вижу причины проблемы (не претендуя на полноту):

1. Некомпетентность некоторых участников по определенным меткам (как в ситуации с численными методами);
2. Бездумное закрытие вопросов, следуя стадному инстинкту — если участник видит, что кто-то проголосовал за закрытие, то он тоже решает проголосовать;
3. Вопросы закрываются просто потому что они простые.

Как их решить:

1. Если вы **не** специалист по теме вопроса, будьте дважды внимательны и закрывайте только тогда, когда уверены, что вопрос действительно требует правки.
2. Не закрывайте вопросы *только* потому что на нем уже висит несколько голосов за закрытие.
3. Причины закрытия «слишком простой» не существует. Не закрывайте вопрос, просто потому что он кажется вам простым.

Comment: Одна из возможных причин - людей раздражает, что автор совсем не потрудился поискать решение самостоятельно.

Comment: Не надо мешать все в кучу. Вопрос по ассемберу действительно закрыли из-за непонимания ассемблера, но вопрос по численным методам был на грани тематики, это совсем другое. Не надо бездумно повторять за Бармалеем обвинения в некомпетентности, вы выбрали не лучший пример для подражания.

Comment: А если по существу, в идеале неплохо бы, чтобы голосование за закрытие как-то ограничивалось самой платформой по меткам. Например, 0 рейтинга по асму - не имеешь права закрывать вопросы с этой меткой. Но не для всех меток, а только для определенного набора признанных "ключевыми".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, а когда вопросы по численным методам стали «на грани темататики»? Что-то мне подсказывает, что вопрос по численным методам был закрыт, потому что б*о*льшая часть участников, проголосовавших за закрытие, подумала, что автор поленился «применить метод Гаусса или что там сейчас изучают» (это цитата из одного комментария под тем вопросом). Что, в принципе, сводится к причине (3) — вопрос закрыли, потому что посчитали слишком простым.

Comment: @eanmos Если вопрос сформулирован так, что больше относится к чистой математике, чем к программированию, то он на грани закрытия как "не по теме". Если бы автор спрашивал, как программно решить, тогда другое дело.  Почему закрыли можно только предполагать, но по крайней мере такое закрытие можно понять, так как допустимость математических вопросов сомнительна.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, но автор просит *алгоритм* для решения системы и, к тому же, ставит метку [tag:c++]. Так что он ближе к программированию, чем к чистой математике.

Comment: Слово "алгоритм" не универсальная защита от закрытия, сложение столбиком - тоже алгоритм. А вот то, что там изначально была метка С++, я не увидел, ее потом удалили. Видимо все же вы правы, закрывать его не стоило. Еще одна проблема - произвол с правками...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, но метка была удалена правильно, ведь алгоритм решения системы не зависит от языка программирования, а значит и вопрос к C++ не относится.

Comment: Если это так, то мы возвращаемся на шаг назад. Нет конкретного языка -> допустимость вопроса на сайте программистов сомнительна. "Алгоритм решения" вполне может быть и про решение на бумажке. Соль тут не в том, что мне не нравится математика, а в том, что это плохой пример произвола при закрытии, так как допустимость вопроса дискуссионна. Эта ветка комментариев это подтвердает.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я не думают, что допустимость вопроса может вызвать сомнение. Практическое применение численных методов связано с программированием, то что связано с программированием — онтопик на сайте, следовательно, численные методы — онтопик на сайте. Вопрос — по численным методам, следовательно, вопрос онтопик на сайте. А касательно «нет конкретного язык → допустимость вопроса сомнительна» — у нас же даже метка есть [tag:любой-язык], как и на большом SO.

Comment: `Некомпетентность некоторых участников по определенным меткам (как в ситуации с численными методами);` откуда такие выводы? Там не все так однозначно

Comment: @tym32167, это одна из возможных причин. Причем довольно правдоподобная. Реальные причины закрытия нужно, конечно, у закрывающих спрашивать. А так мы можем лишь предполагать.

Comment: Эту "возможную" причину озвучил в том вопросе человек, который не голосовал за закрытие. С таким же успехом можно фазу луны назвать как возможную причину. В том же вопросе я оставил свою обратную связь как человек, который подобные вопросы закрывает.  Но вы мой текст проигнорировали и выбрали то, что вам понравилось. Я вас не осуждаю, просто мне не понравилось что вы выдвигаете некомпетентность сообщества как факт, хотя нет ничего, что бы это подтверждало.

Comment: @tym32167, я не совсем понял, про какого человека вы говорите. Касательно вашей обратной связи к тому вопросу: вы предложили использовать метод Гаусса, вам указали на то что этот метод не эффективен. Я готов предположить что некоторые из закрывающих тоже вспомнили этот метод и закрыли вопрос, посчитав слишком простым. Я **не** утверждаю, что вопрос закрыли из-за этого, я **не** утверждаю, что все вопросы закрываются из-за этого. Я лишь озвучил причины проблемы такими, как вижу их я (это написано в ответе). Конечно, я не могу знать наверняка, но я могу *предположить* их и *озвучить*.

Comment: Касательно того, что я проигнорировал ваше сообщение и выбрал то, что мне нравится: я не делал этого! Я не "выбирал то, что мне нравится". Если вы говорите о том, что я не включил причину "закрывающим не нравится халявство" в свой список, то я сделал это не потому что она мне не нравится, а просто потому что я ее не учел. Собственно, я в ответе и написал, что на полноту не претендую. К тому же, сразу после моего ответа, эту причину озвучил @Kromster в своем собственном ответе.

Comment: И последнее: я **не** выдвигал некомпетентность *сообщества*. Я сказал, что участники не компетентны по некоторым меткам. Очевидность чего, думаю, не оставляет сомнений.

Comment: Окей, давайте я поясню. Меня стриггерило вот это `Некомпетентность некоторых участников по определенным меткам (как в ситуации с численными методами);` - хотя если поглядеть на [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10994/179763), то там нет ничего в поддержку этогй теории.Там есть 2 фразы про некомпетентных участников, одна в комменте под вопросом, другая в одном из ответов с рейтингом 0. Получается, про некомпетентность по меткам вы это сами выдумали. Про то, что вы пишете о некомпетентрости именно **по меткам** - это да, я это **по меткам** проглядел, это я признаю.

Comment: @tym32167, а откуда я должен был взять про некомпетентность по меткам? Из учебника из какого-то что-ли?) Сам выдумал, конечно, это же мое видение.

Comment: Ну так я и отписал, что по моему разумению это не соотвествует действительности. Я это прямым текстом написал в первом комментарии. Хорошо, что разобрались кто и что имел ввиду.

Answer (score 13):

Подозреваю, что основной негатив у закрывающих вызывает именно то, что авторы таких вопросов - "халявщики, и палец о палец не ударили, чтобы найти решение". Это видно из текста вопроса.

Как минимум, стоило бы лучше формулировать сами вопросы. Переработав вопрос, можно его значительно улучшить.

Comment: Но негатив участников не должен быть поводом к закрытию вопроса.

Comment: @eanmos сам по себе - нет. Надо учиться "проходить мимо" (см. комикс про "в интернете кто-то не прав"). С другой стороны, хороший вопрос негатива вызывать не станет.

Comment: Последнее утверждение спорно, как показала ситуация с вопросом по численным методам.

Comment: @eanmos если вы про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1198802 то это действительно плохой вопрос. Уберите из него картинку и попробуйте понять о чем он. Как его улучшить - дополнитеть текст описанием матрицы, предметной областью, решаемой задачей.

Comment: (1) Уберите из любого вопроса его содержание и попробуйте понять о чем он. Я к тому, что коэффициенты матрицы — суть вопроса, а то, что они представлены картинкой даже лучше, чем если бы матрица была написана текстом, у нас же нет MathJax или KaTeX. (2) Зачем в вопросе информация о предметной области и решаемой задаче, если вопрос о численных методах?

Comment: @eanmos Ответил вам в https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11089/177188

Answer (score 11):

Меня тоже раздражает постоянное закрытие вопросов. Есть ощущение, что поборники чистоты рядов ruSO слишком часто используют данный инструмент.

В офлайне часто общаюсь с разными старожилами ruSO и многих отворачивает от сайта именно это, но не только. Например такая переписка:

> Кстати, а знаешь, что меня бесит в SO?
> Больше всего убивает "закрытие" вопросов, где люди просят совета с библиотеками или инструментами (в смысле, какую подобрать), а по "правилам сообщества" такие вопросы запрещены.

По мере сил и возможностей стараюсь открывать/поднимать интересные вопросы, не все конечно получается, несколько раз получал уже подзатыльники от других модераторов :)

Comment: Минусы, конечно ожидаемы :) Все это больше походит на борьбу с ветряными мельницами.

Comment: Хотя и согласен с вами, что поиск инструментов и библиотек относительно полезная тема (сам эти метки создавал и продвигал), но приведенный аргумент совершенно неадекватен. Посмотрите, *"Кстати, а знаешь, что меня бесит в SO? Больше всего убивает "закрытие" вопросов, где люди просят **сделать за них домашку / зачет / лабу / работу**, а по "правилам сообщества" такие вопросы запрещены."* - надеюсь понятно сформулировал )

Comment: "Красота в глазах смотрящего" - если переформулировать, то правильность/неправильность определяется юзерами. В данном случае юзер (в реальной жизни, очень крутой IT деятель), делится своими мыслями, они могут вам/нам нравиться или нет, но таков его взгляд и очевидно он этот взгляд дальше транслирует своим коллегам, подчиненным. В сухом остатке мы имеем то что имеем...

Comment: RU SO же не единственный вариант. На Cyberforum не закрывают. Многие сидят и тут и там параллельно, и вполне довольны. А если бесит такой пустяк как закрытие, надо нервы лечить, мне кажется.

Comment: Обращение за помощью к коллегам - это не "сделать домашку". Все мы работаем, и у всех есть желание сэкономить время. 
PS. Недавно прочел: Главное отличие специалиста от эксперта - что специалист дает ответ, а эксперт хочет, чтобы все начали разбираться в теме.

Comment: У очень крутых деятелей, бывает очень неуемное эго ) Что касается прочих форумов, то SO на их фоне это просто чудо чудное! - никакого флуда, страниц уточнений, а только конкретные вопросы и ответы. Цена этого - строгость модерирования контента, да.

Comment: Зато на других форумах можно отвести душу и рассказать вопрошающему, что он таки сам мудак)

Comment: @vp_arth у Ипатьева и тут это неплохо получается (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Зря вы ждали минусов. Сообщество вас поддержало (я тоже плюсанул). Есть много интересных и полезных вопросов, которые формально надо закрыть. Но закрывать их все же не надо. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Давайте уже определимся - мы база вопросов и ответов или сборник задач / биржа бесплатных работников?

И что значит задать вопрос? Является ли просто скидывание свой задачи вопросом?

Вот что указано [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!

Если попытки что то сделать самостоятельно для спрашивающих больше не обязательны, я прошу отразить это в наших правилах и убрать причину закрытия для учебных заданий.

Лично я предпочитаю помогать тем, кому нужна помощь, а не исполнитель.

**UPD**

Вот и [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209201/179763) подъехал, процитирую текст вопроса

> Мне нужен скрипт на 3д турель на с# для товер дефенса. Мне нужно что бы она поворачивалась за 360 градусов по оси z и на 90 градусов по оси х. Желательно так что бы можно было прикрепить его на любой объект то есть турель.

На резонный вопрос "Что именно не получается в написании такого скрипта?" автор отвечает

> мне лень. Ты думаешь я программист? Да. Но знаю ли я с#? Нет. мне он просто нужен и все. Да ты можешь меня осудить за это и будешь прав, но в таком случае мне придется ждать кого либо другого для реализации этого. Короче просто сделай это . Пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

И что, на сайте никто не может написать требуемый скрипт? Может конечно. Но почему то никто не бросается помогать, а напротив, вопрос заминусили, отправили на закрытие и в итоге автор его удалил.

Так что, у нас теперь двойные стандарты? Чем этот вопрос отличается от [вот такого заплюсованного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1205660/179763)? Или вот от [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198802/179763)?

Или это "некомпетентные" люди понабежали и заминусили хороший вопрос?

Comment: По вашей логике SO вообще нужно закрывать, потому что на все вопросы можно найти ответ в книгах, документации, исходниках, научных статьях и так далее. Давай тогда все вопросы закрывать: авторы же не трудятся найти решение. Посмотрите общий топ вопросов. Да подавляющее большинство из них -- это канонические вопросы типа "вычисления с плавающей запятой не работают". Ну просто миллион книг и статей уже на эту тему. Что теперь, этот вопрос тоже закрываем? Мы же не биржа бесплатных работников, чтобы читать книги за авторов, да?

Comment: Послушайте, мы же здесь собрались, чтобы делится своим опытом и помогать другим. Пускай вопрос простой и найти ответ можно за секунду. Но вы-то знаете *где* искать, *как* искать и *что*. Тот, кто только начал заниматься программированием понятия не имеет как и что искать. Это наше *проклятье знания* -- мы думаем, что другие знают столько же, сколько и мы. Но это не так. Не забывайте об этом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Далее. Если автор как в приведенном вами примере, открытым текстом говорит "сделай за меня". Конечно, я внутренне буду негодовать, мне это не понравится чисто по-человечески. Но даже если мне не нравится поведение вопрошающего, это не значит что вопрос плохой (говорю не про этот случай). Этот вопрос может помочь еще тысяче человек. И негатив к одному не должен быть поводом к закрытию хорошего и полезного вопроса.

Comment: Привилегия закрытия дана не для того чтобы вершить правосудие над лентями, а для того чтобы сохранять базу знаний, которую мы собираем уже годами, в чистоте и порядке. Не превышайте свои полономочия.

Comment: `По вашей логике SO вообще нужно закрывать, потому что на все вопросы можно найти ответ` - не приписывате мне то, что я не говорил. И если вы обратите внимание на мой профиль, то увидите, что я как раз из тех, кто охотно делится опытом с другими участниками.

Comment: Я не против помочь тысяче человек, но я против халявщиков, которые используют площадку как решебник. Молодые и неопытные действительно не знают что и где искать, для этого и создан поисковик - если искал и не нашел, приходи и раскажи, что ты искал, где искал, что за проблему решаешь - и тут наверняка с таким вопросом помогут.

Comment: `Не превышайте свои полономочия` - вы опять выдаете свои фантазии за действительное. Вы можете мне конкретно указать где и когда и какие именно полномочия я превышал с указанием конкретных правил, что я нарушил? Почему вы думаете, что можете мне диктовать, что мне делать? Заметье, я вам не диктовал ничего, но я выразил свое несогласие с вами, и мне для этого даже не пришлось ничего выдумывать.

Comment: про полномочия это я не вам, а тем читателям, кто превышает :)

Comment: С этим я согласен, полномочия не для того, чтобы сводить личные счеты или убирать хорошие, но неугодные вопросы. Я вообще когда чувствую, что меня вопросы начинают раздражать своей постановкой или некомпетеноностью или стилем изложения, то просто делаю перерыв, чтобы это пережить. Но это все таки не относится к тебе нашего обсуждения.

Comment: Вы говорите, что если автор вопроса не привел своих попыток найти ответ, то он -- халявщик. А если он халявщик, то вы не против закрытия этого вопроса, потому что SO не бесплатная биржа. А я говорю, что большая часть вопросов на SO не содержит попытки найти решение самостоятельно. Исходя из вашей логики делаем вывод, что большую часть  SO нужно закрыть. Правильно?

Comment: Нет, как раз таки относится, это же (по-моему) одна из причин закрытия хороших вопросов, что мы и обсуждаем.

Comment: `большая часть вопросов на SO не содержит попытки найти решение самостоятельно` приведите конкретные цифры, сколько вопросов от халявшиков у нас есть, какой процент они занимает от всех вопросов и сколько из них не было закрыто? Я не отрицаю, что могут быть полезные вопросы среди них, но это скорее исключение, чем правило. Я на сайте уже 5.5 лет и уже 1130 дней подряд, я голосую за закрытие вопросов-халявщиков почти каждый день.

Comment: И, кстати говоря, отсутсвие попыток решения вопроса не всегда является флагом к закрытию. Я каждый раз задаю вопрос автору что именно он сделал, чтобы решить его проьблему. У меня сотни таких комментариев под вопросами. И очень редко, но бывает, что автор просто не знал, что надо указать свои попытки, и таким людям я с радостью помогаю. Но если автор не отвечает или сам признается, что не делал ничего самостоятельно, или это просто очевидно из вопроса, тогда я могу голосовать за закрытие.

Comment: Конкретные цифры не приведу, по понятным причинам. Однако, интереса ради, посмотрел топ 5 своих ответов — ни один из вопросов, на которые я ответил не содержит попытки найти решение. Причем каждый из вопросов получил положительный баланс голосов. Т. е. сообщество посчитало их полезными.

Comment: Т. е. если автор признается, что не пытался сам найти ответ или это очевидно из вопроса, то вы голосуете за закрытие? Тогда мы возвращаемся к «превышению полномочий».

Comment: Вы видимо не прочитали, что я вам ответил. Как я уже написал, полезные вопросы среди таких могут быть, но это скорее исключение, чем правило. И если уж обвиняете меня в "превышении полномочий", то покажите мне где и что конкретно я превысил.

Comment: Да ни в чем я вас не обвиняю, просто вы написали «но если автор не отвечает или сам признается, что не делал ничего самостоятельно, или это просто очевидно из вопроса, тогда я могу голосовать за закрытие», вот я и спрашиваю, правильно ли я понимаю, что по вашему мнению факт того, что автор не делал ничего самостоятельно может являться причиной к закрытию вопроса?

Comment: Я и отвечаю, в большинстве случаев да, для этого есть даже причина на закрытие - см про учебные задания. По моему опыту примерно 90% вопросов без самостоятельных попыток что либо сделать являются либо домашками либо просьбами сделать задачу за автора.

Comment: Я, кстати, поробовал поискать все свои голоса на закрытие и сколько из тех вопросов осталось открытыми (не набрали нужное колво голосов), но не хватает времени разобраться со схемой данных, если вам интересно будет посмотреть самому - https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/queries

Comment: Вот только вчера вам пример скидывал с домашкой, вот и новый пример подоспел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209726/179763

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема со всеми этими домашками заключается не в том, что автор ничего не делает сам, а в том, что большая часть таких вопросов бесполезна для всех, кроме самого автора. И нам нужно как-то разделять вопросы типа [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209660) и [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209363/185348). В обоих вопросах не указаны самостоятельные попытки разобраться. Но, первый очевидно, должен быть закрыт, второй — вполне имеет место быть. P. S. Ваша ссылка уже мертва.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116662/discussion-between-eanmos-and-tym32167).

Comment: Я согласен, надо разделять домашки и вопросы, полезные для широкой аудитории. Например, вот эти ([раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1011642/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/888860/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1064142/179763)) тоже не содержат попыток, но я счел, что такие вопросы должны иметь ответ, так как они помогут широкому кругу программистов. А вот такие вопросы ([раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1205660/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198802/179763)) по моему мнению являются чем то специфичным, не для широкого круга.

Comment: Об этом уже [писали в другом треде](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10994/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82#comment46769_11054)

Comment: Но мне кажется, нет таких четких критериев, чтобы сказать, полезен отдельно взятый вопрос или нет. Об этом то весь и сыр бор.

Comment: В чат не пойду, там мне зависать пока некогда.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116677/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167----).

Comment: @tym32167  если вы разделяете вопросы на "специфичные" и "неспецифичные", тогда просто надо убить метку [tag:численные-методы] - и дело с концом. Да и у меня будет в разы меньше поводов спорить, мне оно как бы не надо, я и на английском поотвечаю в узкоспециализированных сообществах.

Comment: @AntonMenshov не вижу причинно-следсвенной связи в ваших выводах. Вы, когда задавали свой вопрос наверное расчитвали получить обратную связь в виде ответа. Я вам постарался её дать. У вас один образ мыслей, у меня другой. Вы привели свои доводы, я привел свои. Мы пообщались и разошлись миром. Потому я не очень понял, к чему вы написали то, что написали и какой реакции вы от меня хотите.

Comment: Там я вашу позицию понял. А тут - я увидел очень странное разделение на специфичное-неспецифичное, о чем речи не было. Мне лично непонятно, почему вдруг раз вопросы по численным методам считаются слишком специфичными и не для широкого круга, потому их надо жестче фильтровать.

Comment: @AntonMenshov все почти так, как вы описали. В ходе дискуссии тут я пошел глядеть вопросы, на которые отвечал сам и которые были более мнеее заплюсованы и где бы не было попыток автора. И я такие вопросы нашел. Я стал думать, почему я сам одни вопросы посчитал хорошими, а другие нет, хотя и там и там не было попыток автора. Я увидел различие только в том, какой размер аудитории может захватить вопрос и ответ. В моем случае я отвечал на общие вопросы по предмету, но минусовал вопросы-задачки.

Comment: @AntonMenshov И, если вы почитаете тред выше до конца, увидите, что проблема оказалась именно в том, что нет четких критериев, как отделить одни от других. На этом дискуссия и остановилась. Почему вы решили, что я против метки численных методов мне не ведомо, но это определенно не так.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю причина тому - сам механизм закрытия, плюс спорное качество вопроса. Если хоть один человек поставил хоть один голос на "закрытие" - то вопрос будет "висеть" в очереди на проверку. Если человек не потрудится и не отзовёт свой голос - то вопрос будет висеть с предложениями "закрыть" очень долго (udp 4 дня). Может ли быть проигнорирован этот голос - я думаю нет.

О качестве. Качество вопроса - спорное. Учитывая краткость вопроса - его всё таки можно отнести к вопросу "халявщиков", а не "интересных трюков". Человек просто спросил, ему просто ответили. Возможно потому, что ответ не составил особого труда и лёгкие немного странные вопросы по ассемблеру массово не раздражают участников. Кстати, в это же время появился второй вопрос по [ассемблеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189159/assembler) - идеальный-вывод- содержимого-регистров который более полный, чем данный - тем не менее, он почему-то никому по душе не пришёлся. Я всё же считаю что обсуждаемый вопрос - менее качественный, чем я привёл (моё личное мнение). Можно ли улучшить качество?  Возможно нужна метка соревнование, или какие-то пояснения зачем это нужно - тогда вопрос будет более интересным. Почему за такой простой вопрос проголосовало много людей - думаю это странно, может интерес решить простую задачу привлёк, а может звёзды так сошлись, мне кажется, автору вопроса повезло.

Вернемся к механизму закрытия. В первый же день вопрос получил один голос на закрытие. Человек, поставивший голос - возможно больше не заходил на форум. А может заходил - но не посчитал нужным отозвать голос. Дальше вопрос несколько дней висел в очереди проверок. Одни люди считали, что вопрос спорный или например, они не знают ассемблер - и пропускали голосования, но нашлось 3 или 4 голоса, чтобы вопрос закрыли, и я считаю, что это нормально с точки зрения психологии. Так задуман интерфейс SO. До тех пор, пока вопрос не закроется окончательно - анyулировать или оспорить закрытие - нельзя. Нормального противовеса закрытию - нет. Т.е. следующая фаза такого вопроса - закрытие. Только когда вопрос закрылся - один из участников может поставить голосование на переоткрытие - и вопрос тогда откроется, учитывая положительное к-во голосов за вопрос - голоса на переоткрытие найдутся. Т.е. я считаю что это нормальный жизненный цикл относительно хорошего вопроса, который получил
хотя бы один голос на закрытие. По другому аннулировать один голос на закрытие не привлекая участника, который поставил голос на закрытие - не получится.

Comment: Бывало, что приходилось давать пятый голос за закрытие, просто чтобы ускорить процесс переоктрытия =) Если бы был какой-то TTL голоса за закрытие было бы лучше..

Comment: @vp_arth [TTL есть](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/339911).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вот, уже лучше. =)

Comment: Т.е. один голос за закрытие будет анулирован через 4 дня, а 4-ре дня он будет маячить в очереди проверок? Даже если в проверках будет много выбрано оставить открытым? Мне кажется 4 дня - слишком долго, но думаю эти условия будет сложно оспорить.

Comment: `Кстати в это же время появился второй вопрос по ассемблеру` - не в это же время, а в 2013 году. Он поднялся только после того как вы на него ответили. Ну и лично для меня субъективно вопрос про `dec` без `dec` кажется интересным, а вопрос по переводу между системами счисления, да еще под DOS - не особо.

Comment: @insolor Вопрос поднялся системой скорее всего из-за отсутствующей зелёной галочки - это другая проблема системы. Я не сразу заметил что вопрос - древний, только сейчас. Вывод регистров из ассемблера - очень нужная вещь, кто на ассемблере писал программы побольше - думаю должны оценить такой вопрос. Но вопрос "хорошести" вопроса тут решается голосованием, исходя из голосов - первый вопрос лучше.