# Требование минимального воспроизводимого примера

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

В последнее время разбираюсь с новой для меня темой и стал активно задавать вопросы. И стали мне в эти вопросы прилетать минусы и голоса за закрытие с формулировкой

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Примеры вопросов

- [Работа с CComPtr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1283631/221228)
- [Копирование SAFEARRAY в вектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287052/221228)

Что не так с этими вопросами? Или нынче в вопрос нужно включать весь код программы, чтобы ее можно было скопипастить и запустить AS IS? Так вопросы же не "почему не работает этот код", а об общих принципах работы. И куски кода там скорее для комментирования происходящего.

Или я действительно чего-то не понимаю и так формулировать вопросы нельзя?

Вот здесь [Перестаньте закрывать все подряд](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11084/221228) обсуждается подобная проблема, но в этом топике упор идет на вопросы о некоторых базовых принципах конкретного языка/технологии.

Comment: Первый вроде ок - там вообще не про отладку. Во втором - да, скорее всего закрывающие ожидали примера, который можно будет скопировать и запустить.

Comment: Чисто мое мнение... В первом вопросе информации - кода - слишком мало, во втором - слишком много. Что такое `AddRef`, как именно оно вызывается etc - это для тех, кто не знаком с конкретной библиотекой, темный лес. Во втором опять же не получается взять, засунуть код в компилятор и посмотреть, что же не так.  Хотя вопрос фактически о конкретном `if constexpr`, и было бы куда проще, если бы был тестовый пример в 10 строк, в котором бы воспроизводилась проблема. Чтобы на вопрос ответили, он должен быть или очень интересным - вызовом, когда плевать на время, или таким, чтоб за 5 минут ответить :)

Comment: @Harry `AddRef` это стандартный метод подсистемы COM. На вопросе стоит метка COM. Вопрос об использовании объектов в рамках технологии COM и адресован тем, кто работает с этой технологией из c++. Где криминал? Мало кода? Так больше там и быть не может. Вопрос о стандартном поведении стандартного класса. Второй вопрос был изначально задан без всякого `if constexpr`. Предположение о том, что проблема решается через `if constexpr` была моя и уже после того, как прилетел минус и голос за закрытие.

Comment: Повторюсь еще раз - **для тех, кто не знаком**.

Comment: Лично я когда вопросы с кодом задаю, то обычно использую псевдокод или выдумываю новые сущности, сохраняя общий принцип или проблему. Например, если у меня есть класс `SomeClassWithMoreFields`, в котором есть десять полей и сто пятьдесят аннотаций, то для вопроса я переименовываю его в класс `Dog`, например, и оставляю только те поля, которые непосредственно относятся к вопросу. Общий принцип не теряется, зато другим людям проще воспринимать такое.

Comment: @Harry я не знаком с кучей всего в библиотеке unity, но это же не повод закрывать все вопросы по unity на c#.

Comment: @PashaPash [Удивленно] Я голосовал за закрытие этого вопроса? Я хотя бы говорил, что его следует закрыть? P.S. Еще раз пересмотрел. Вопрос совершенно не в COM, а в том, вызывается или нет при некотором (каком?) наследовании некоторая функция дважды. Да, пожалуй, вопрос закрыт не зря...

Comment: @Harry там вообще не о наследовании. CBasePtr и CComPtr - это стандартные классы ATL, вроде бы, AddRef и QueryInterface - стандартные методы. и вопрос о поведении этой стандартной обертки при определенном порядке вызовов. Собственно, если этот вопрос закрыт не зря - то что в него надо было добавить, чтобы он остался открытым? код ATL? тогда, получается, в каждый вопрос нужно добавлять полный код любой сторонней библиотеки. от jquery до unity.

Comment: @Harry ну или метки ATL на нем не хватает? ради метки закрывать вопрос - это как-то странно

Comment: это и есть суть вопроса топикастера, насколько я понял. его вопрос закрыли как требующий добавления кода. какой именно код нужно добавить? добавить код всех библиотек, на случай, если кто-то с ними не знаком - это так себе решение

Comment: @PashaPash Если это вопрос по COM - его лучше переформулировать, если по С++ - тем более... Вобщем-то, у нас какая-то странная дискуссия - вы меня вроде как обвиняете в том, что я не делал, я вроде как должен оправдываться за то, чего не делал. Я свое мнение высказал, ну и хватит.

Comment: @Harry я не обвиняю, просто у меня ощущение, что вопрос закрыли просто так, те, кто со стандартной библиотекой не знаком. пытаюсь понять, нормально это или нет

Comment: @Harry Это вопрос по библиотеке ATL, которая реализует технологию COM в C++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По первому вопросу:

Как прямо сказано в причине закрытия, требование минимального воспроизводимого примера касается **только** просьб помочь с отладкой.

Вопросы по поведению библиотек (особенно, стандартных библиотек) должны включать в себя достаточно контекста, чтобы остальные могли понять, какая именно библиотека используется.

Требования к копипасте библиотеки целиком в тело вопроса нет. Достаточно упоминания (хотя бы в виде тэга). Если на вопросе стоит метка ATL - то макросы из winnt.h копипастить не нужно.

Наличие кода в вопросе не превращает вопрос в "просьбу помочь с отладкой". В случае теоретического вопроса по поведению библиотеки - подразумевается, что отвечающий знаком с библиотекой. Незнакомство конкретного участника с конкретной библиотекой может быть поводом просто пройти мимо вопроса, но никак не может быть поводом закрыть вопрос. У нас нет причины закрытия "я с этим не знаком" :)

В противном случае - вопросы, хоть немного упоминающие любые библиотеки - автоматом запрещены. И тогда на SO просто нельзя было бы задать вопросы по большей части современной JS разработки и почти по всему C#.

---

Почему этот конкретный вопрос закрыт? Тяжело сказать, но судя по всему, *незнакомые с ATL* закрывающие подумали что в фразе

> В конструкторе класса `CBasePtr`, который является родительским классом для класса `CComPtr`, я вижу вызов `AddRef()`

вы говорите не о стандартных классах, а о каких-то самописных своих классах, код которых вы не привели.

Comment: А ведь я в коде четко написал **ATL::**CComPtr. Да, на вопросе не было метки `atl`. Наверное, именно в этом и есть основная причина