# в очереди проверок на закрытие вопросов можно ведь голосовать и за «оставить открытым»

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

неоднократно встречал в дискуссиях, вопросах и ответах на мете довольно распространённую, как мне кажется, позицию: «в очереди проверок на закрытие вопросов закрываются вопросы, которые стоило бы оставить открытыми» (моя вольная формулировка).

о распространённости такой позиции говорит наличие (и голоса «за») такого, например, вопроса на мете: [Перестаньте закрывать все подряд](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11084/178576).

ни в коем случае не пытаясь давать оценку такой позиции, осмелюсь лишь напомнить (фраза вынесена и в заголовок):

**в очереди проверок на закрытие вопросов можно ведь голосовать и за «оставить открытым»**.

необходимо всего лишь <s>пять голосов</s> три<sup>*</sup> голоса «оставить открытым»<sup>**</sup> для того, чтобы вопрос был удалён из очереди. и один из этих голосов может быть ваш!

---

<sup>*</sup> по поводу количества голосов «оставить открытым» см. комментарии под вопросом.

<sup>**</sup> в качестве голоса за «оставить открытым» принимается, кстати, и выбор пункта «править» в списке действий в диалоге проверки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы добавил, что в очереди  «Голоса за закрытие» есть кнопка [Фильтр], которою могут выбрать не желающие просматривать всё подряд, и установив "свою метку" они смогут проголосовать «оставить открытым» на попавшие в очередь «по воле божьей» вопросы, содержащие только эту метку.

Comment: Я не очень понял, в чем суть данного поста. Довести информацию, что надо очереди разгребать и или о том, что в очереди на закрытие можно голосовать против? Так это вроде всем известно, кто участвует.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а тем, кто не участвует (например, придерживаясь озвученной в вопросе позиции), возможно, не известно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin достаточно 3-х голосов "Оставить открытым", вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/661568

Comment: @PashaPash, не знал об этом. думал, что ситуация симметрична, чтобы задание удалилось из очереди (помимо истечения таймаута): пять за закрытие, либо пять за «оставить открытым» (+правка). // а это точно не единичный (или редкий) случай? // о! что-то вспоминается смутное про «единогласность»: вроде когда-то что-то встречал по этому поводу: если нет разброса мнений, то количество голосов может быть и меньше. но не уверен, что ничего не путаю.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нет, вроде всегда было 3 голоса на выбрасывание. может даже 2 в некоторых очередях - но в очереди низкокачественных модераторам прилетала тревога при спорных результатах голосования

Comment: @PashaPash, ну, если таковое соотношение 5/3 имеется сейчас, то, вероятно, и в [предлагаемом изменении порога](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11774/178576) это соотношение надо бы учесть (и озвучить).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin один "выглядит нормально", автокликер разгребет очередь за пару дней

Comment: @PashaPash, надо подкинуть эту идею особо активным «борцам с [закрывашками](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8)». // но пары дней не хватит: 600 висит в очереди, даже по 20 в день — это будет месяц.