# О модерации и правилах поведения

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, модерация, тревоги

**Вводная:**

Данный вопрос не нацелен на жалобу и конкретных участников данного сообщества (поэтому не будет прямых ссылок на конкретную ситуацию).

**Мотивация:**

Целью является понять принципы и правила для дальнейшего применения. Поскольку я использую данный ресурс как хорошую базу данных для практического применения и желания развиваться, мне хочется иметь качественный ресурс со своими принципами, которые проявляются, например, в возможности делиться своим опытом (ответы на собственные вопросы), получать опыт и критику и что немаловажно на русском языке. Поскольку я владею несколькими языками в т.ч. и английским и конкретно для меня не составляет труда читать документацию в оригинале, но развитие индустрии в целом не должно задерживаться из-за языка на котором общаются те или иные специалисты. Я принял ту сторону, в которой нет ограничения на знания по причине не знания английского.

**Основная часть:**

Сама ситуация состоит в том, что я взял на себя ответственность уделять время модерации на данном ресурсе. На данный момент я использую тревоги и правки. Да, по причине того, что я не так давно решил этим заниматься могут случаться и промахи с моей стороны. Но сегодня меня просто выбило из колеи, так как я совсем не понял поведения, как я считаю, старших товарищей. Называю их старшими товарищами только потому, что у них рейтинга и возможностей побольше, чем у меня.

В очередной раз проверяя вопрос из очереди проверок, я поставил тревогу, поскольку данный вопрос являлся из разряда: "Вот вам ТЗ, надо решить". С моей точки зрения, данный вопрос является интересным, но политике данного ресурса  не соответствует, конкретно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) можно найти почему. Поставил тревогу и забыл. Через некоторое время увидел, что у данного вопроса появился ответ. Ответ оставил старший товарищ с хорошим рейтингом и, на сколько я понимаю, хорошим представлением о том как работает ресурс. Подискутировав с ним и с модератором в комментариях, что тоже не приветствуется я сделал несколько выводов:

1. не стоит придерживаться правил, если на кону стоит рейтинг или задача интересная,
2. можно выкладывать интересные или рутинные задачи из моей практики и экономить время-деньги, да еще и судя по вопросу, репутацию себе поднимать

**Вопрос:**

Я могу не понимать как это работает или собрать в своей голове так, как хочу это видеть только я. Я прошу  объяснить, где я ошибаюсь? И как в дальнейшем не отвлекать модераторов бесполезными тревогами?

**PS**
На момент написания данного вопроса, моя беседа с модератором и старшим товарищем уже удалена, как не относящаяся к вопросу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124624/discussion-on-question-by------).

Comment: «не стоит придерживаться правил, если на кону стоит рейтинг или задача интересная» — я уже больше года воюю против такого подхода... Но модераторы упорно предпочитают поддерживать нарушение правил -_-

Comment: @andreymal мне кажется один конкретный модератор

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> не стоит придерживаться правил, если на кону стоит рейтинг или задача интересная

Нет, это полный бред. Какая бы репутация ни была у написавшего это, не слушайте его. Если вопрос интересный, но не соответствует правилам, это повод его отредактировать, чтобы он соответствовал правилам. Интересность никак не может отменять правила из-за своей субъективности. Насчет "на кону стоит рейтинг", если вам кто-то прямо такое заявляет, это и вовсе стыд и позор. Рейтинг (точнее репутация) должен отражать полезный вклад, ведь от него зависят довольно серьезные возможности модерации на сайте, вплоть до удаления сообщений. Печально, что и модератор, судя по вашему сообщению, поддерживал репофармерство.

> можно выкладывать интересные или рутинные задачи из моей практики и экономить время-деньги, да еще и судя по вопросу, репутацию себе поднимать

Нет, не можно. Stackoverflow - это сайт вопросов и ответов, а не сервис бесплатного решения задач. Если у участника есть "рутинная задача", он должен осмыслить ее, попытаться решить самостоятельно, и если не получилось, задать вопрос с конкретным описанием проблемы. Про это нигде напрямую не написано, потому что владельцам сайта важны объемы аудитории, а это бы отпугнуло массовую публику. Чтобы из этих объемов, поступающих на сайт, отсеивать некачественное, и существуют механизмы модерации.

Вообще, довольно интересно, что теперь в систему добавилась и экономическая составляющая. Что, есть свидетельства, что кто-то реальные задачи с фриланс бирж скидывает на Stackoverflow, и имеет таким образом прибыль? Если это так, то проблема куда серьезнее, чем фарм рейтингов.

> И как в дальнейшем не отвлекать модераторов бесполезными тревогами?

Тревоги на закрытие вопросов обрабатываются не модераторами, а обычными участниками. Ставьте смело, если вы будете часто ошибаться, у вас просто автоматически заблокируется возможность ставить тревоги, так что серьезно перегрузить очередь вы не сможете.

Comment: я должен здесь отметить, что на мой взгляд модератор открыто не поддерживал "репофармерство". Разговор был вполне обстоятельным.

Comment: должен осмыслить ее, попытаться решить самостоятельно - но при этом в вопросе не должно быть лишней информации, фразы "я пытался, не получилось", как и приветствия, подлежал вырезанию, и этот кусок абсолютно неверифицируем. Так что можно идти почти в каждый вопрос и голосовать за закрытие с комментарием "автор не написал, что сам пытался решить проблему".

Comment: вот вам конкретный пример - последний вопрос, на который вы ответили. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1286082/. Автор просто притащил задачу. Через один вопрос от в списке - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1264466/ - то же самое, вообще никаких попыток решения. Думаю, по истории такого можно много накопать, 80% вопросов - такие же. И вы почему-то на эти вопросы отвечаете, а не закрываете. Скорее всего потому что задача интересная, и уже не до правил :)

Comment: вот еще примеры -https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1253677/ - простая проблема, никаких попыток самостоятельного решения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1232834/ - "не могу сориентироваться" - это не попытка решения. И такого полно.

Comment: @PashaPash эти вопросы не за что закрывать. Попыток нет, но они не домашки и на скинутую задачу с работы вроде совсем не похожи? Нигде я не принимал решения "не закрывать" только на основе того, что они интересные. Вы посмотрели мои последние ответы, но вы также могли бы посмотреть мои последние голоса за закрытие, где увидели бы настоящий мусор, который я все-таки закрываю, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1285691/240512

Comment: "этот кусок абсолютно неверифицируем" - это так. Но это не значит, что надо поощрять задавание любых вопросов без попытки решения. Как минимум потому что таким образом будут плодиться дубликаты, так как чаще всего люди сталкиваются с одними и теми же типовыми задачами.

Comment: эти вопросы не за что закрывать - "он должен осмыслить ее, попытаться решить самостоятельно, и если не получилось, задать вопрос", в противном случае, вопрос задать "не можно". раз "не можно" - значит, вопрос - оффтопик, и должен быть закрыт. вот я и привел вам примеры вопросов, которые их авторам было не можно задавать, по вашему определению - а вы их наоборот, поощрили ответом.

Comment: Настоящий мусор, который я все-таки закрываю - это пример домашки, а тут вообще не о ней. Вы запрещаете топикастеру тянуть сюда рутину без попыток решения, но при этом сами регулярно отвечаете именно на такие вопросы. Вы определитесь, или все такие вопросы - оффтопик, как вы ответили топикастеру, либо все они не онтопик. А то сейчас, судя по вашим ответам, вы пользуетесь принципом "иногда не до правил"

Answer (score 10):

Имеет ли значение, как оформлен вопрос, если вы поняли его суть и сами хотите даль ответ? - решать только вам.
Лично я долго был прямо [против домашек](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11054/179763), а потом увидел, что сам домашки кому то решал, просто потому, что мне было интересно. И я [не один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198802/179763) такой.
Мало того, нет четкого критерия, который отделит домашку от не-домашки. Мало того, некоторые вопросы, которые мне кажутся чисто домашкой, другому человеку [могут казаться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10994/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82/11054#comment46769_11054) полезыми.

Таким образом

- Нет четких критериев, как понять является ли вопрос домашкой
- Нет четких критериев определения полезности вопроса
- Нет обязательных формальных требований к качеству вопроса. В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) есть только советы (`Вот несколько советов, позволяющих увеличить шансы на получение ответа`)
- Как следствие, каждый раз, когда мы принимаем решение о закрытии или не-закрытии вопроса, мы руководствуемся только своим разумением, не основываясь на каких то конкретных и четких правилах.

Вы привели ссылку на [онтопик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), давайте её вместе почитаем формулировки

> Активные участники с высокой репутацией, а модераторы их скорее всего поддержат, могут закрыть или заморозить ваш вопрос, если им **покажется** ...

То есть активные участники и модераторы голосуют по наитию, а не по каким то правилам. Этому есть причина - перечень формальных правил для вопросов будет размером с книгу и никто такой текст читать не будет.

---

Как итог:

1. Вы тут никому и ничем не обязаны. Вам тут никто ничем не обязан.
2. Высокая репутция не означает ум, лояльность или образец для подражания. Высокая репутация означает только количество заработанных виртуальных баллов.
3. Если задача интересная, не является дубликатом, и вы хотите её решить, то решайте на здоровье.
4. Если вам **покажется**, что вопрос требует внимания модератора, то смело его вызывайте.
5. Если вы тут чисто чтобы нафармить рейтинг, то к 20-25к вы будете разочарованы, так как дальше уже ради рейтинга ползти бессмысленно, вы просто обнаружите, что потратили своё время интенсивного труда впустую. Это число никак не сделает вас умнее или счастливее. У меня 25к рейтинга за 6 лет и это число само по себе ни разу не принесло мне какой либо пользы.
6. Если вы хотите помогать людям - помогайте.
7. Если у вас есть задачи, которые ещё не решались на SO и вы хотите поделиться задачей и её решением - то вперед, никто вас не осудит (а если и осудит, то и фиг с ним).

Answer (score 8):

> не стоит придерживаться правил, если на кону стоит рейтинг или задача интересная

Правил стоит придерживатся. Но:

- Нет правила, по которому вы *обязаны* проголосовать за закрытие возможного офтопика. Модерация - это добровольный вклад. Пройти мимо и ничего не сделать - не нарушение. Ну да, морально нехорошо, и так делать не стоит. Но не более. А вот проголосовать "оставить открытым" в очереди проверов на явном оффтопике - это нарушение, и если слишком часто так "промахиваться" - то доступ к очередям проверок отзовут.
- Нет правила, запрещающего вам ответить на любой вопрос. Не стоит отвечать на явный оффтопик (включая домашки), чтобы не давать им положительную обратную связь. Но в остальном  - на что хотите, на то и отвечайте.
- Нет правила, по которому в вопросе должны быть попытки решить его самостоятельно (за исключением явных домашек). Нет правила, что в вопросе вообще должен быть код. В вопросе должно быть *только* описание проблемы, без лишнего шума. Все "привет, я тут не могу решить проблему, долго-долго пробовал сам, не получилось" подлежат вырезанию. Вырезать "пробовал сам" и тут же закрыть за "нет попыток самостоятельного решения"? Я очень сомневаюсь, что это разумный подход.
- Нет правила, запрещающего задавать на SO рутинные вопросы. Более того, рутинные вопросы - это и есть [основной онтопик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Вот определение онтопика:

> Какие вопросы можно задавать?
> Здесь можно задать **любой** вопрос, относящийся: ...

Там нет ни слова про осмысление, долгие попытки решить самостоятельно и преодоление стыда при спрашивании у "старших товарищей". Есть про "поищите готовый ответ" - чтобы дубликаты не плодить. "Любой" - это любой, без доп условий.

Более того, сама суть SO - собрать базу знаний из кучи этих самых рутинных вопросов, чтобы  ответ можно было найти, а не тратить человекогоды на решение одного и того же рутинного вопроса вместо того, чтобы просто спросить.

Конкретный пример - рутинная задача из моей практики. [Получить размеры всех таблиц в SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/). Это задача вполне решабельная по документации. Занимает от 15 минут до нескольких часов, в зависимости от скилла разработчика. И что ж получается, т.к. этот вопрос всегда можно решить самостоятельно, пользуясь документацией - такой вопрос нельзя задать на Stack Overflow? Так зачем Stack Overflow тогда нужен :)

Comment: Подписываюсь. И дважды под последним предложением. А в целом развернутый логический ответ. В одном могу только усомниться - `явный оффтопик (включая домашки)` - где грань? Каждый участник любой вопрос может отнести как к явному оффтопику или к домашке, так и напротив, и каждый же участник будет прав. Убедите меня, что какой-то конкретный вопрос является домашкой, если, например, сам же автор вопроса не упоминает о том, что это есть домашка.

Comment: @Sevastopol' оговорки про домашки - исключительно ради местной традиции считать, что если на каждую домашку от аккаунта-однодневки тратить силы 5-х закрывающих, вместо простого минусования, то их, якобы, станет меньше. Иначе участники почему-то читают "решить проблему" как "решить учебную задачу", и начинают выплескивать свою ненависть к "студентам-халявщикам" на обычных задающих вопросы

Comment: Про включение кода в ответ и попытки решить. Есть вопросы чисто теоретические, в котором, по умолчанию может не быть кода. Есть вопросы, которые не могут включать этот код, но супер когда автор указывает свои мысли, на подобие: "Я считаю, что "та" технология могла бы сработать вот так и вот так". Тогда понятно становится куда думает ТС и дать релевантный ответ становится в разы проще. И база пополняется взглядом на проблему с разных сторон. Я точно не сторонник: "Вложи код, иначе закроют вопрос". Вот когда вообще ничего нет, вот тогда и возникают вопросы у сообщества

Comment: @Дмитрий ок, не подсматривая в поиск, оцените вопрос: "Как из скрипта на Питоне послать письмо с вложением? Нужен простейший пример посылки письма с вложением через внешний SMTP сервер, например, smtp.yandex.ru.". Хороший вопрос или "ТЗ, вообще ничего нет"? :)

Comment: @PashaPash не сказать что хороший, но я бы не закрывал

Comment: @Дмитрий это вопрос №1 на ruSO: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/. Хотя вроде как в чистом виде ТЗ и "сделайте за меня" без попыток решить проблему самостоятельно

Comment: @PashaPash позволю себе не согласиться. Это ни разу не ТЗ. Вопрос в том, как применять данную технологию без определенного практического применения. Как пример, который всегда есть в документации:"как воспользоваться данной сущностью". Ответ на вопрос может применяться и адаптироваться под задачи не связанные конкретикой с вопросом. Для базы знаний самое то.

Comment: @Дмитрий ну как не ТЗ? Вы, как python разработчик, можете сделать это самостоятельно, пользуясь стандартной документацией? Значит - ТЗ.

Comment: @PashaPash у меня еще и своих мыслей вагон и маленькая тележка, с таким ТЗ я такого наворочу))