# Что именно надо конкретизировать в вопросе по теме математики?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Есть такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1504235/195342), закрытый как "необходимо конкретизировать".

Я бы еще понял, если бы математиконенавистники :) закрывали его как не соответствующий тематике или хотя бы как вопрос, где не изложена попытка самостоятельного решения.

Но "необходимо конкретизировать"? (по крайней мере 4 голоса были поданы именно с этим вердиктом)

Мое мнение — вопрос действительно интересный и нетривиальный, и вполне конкретно сформулированный (так что я уже подал голос за переоткрытие), но это в данном случае неважно.

Хотелось бы услышать, что именно надо конкретизировать ("Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме")? Какие *несколько* вопросов видят здесь авторы голосов за закрытие?

Конечно, это всего лишь частный случай общей проблемы закрытия вопросов с использованием некорректных причин, но я не собираюсь поднимать здесь дискуссию, которая утопит самое себя в раздорах. Меня интересует конкретно этот вопрос. При закрытии авторы голосов известны (правда, неизвестно, кто именно и какую причину выдвинул, указывается-то та, за которую большинство... но при 4 голосах за закрытие все они были "необходимо конкретизировать"), так что вполне можно попросить их обосновать свое решение. Что я и прошу сделать.

Comment: если б не комментарий под вопросом,  я бы тоже отдал голос за закрытие, триггернул на тему самого вопроса и отсутствие попытки решения.  Причину бы точно указал другую. С другой стороны, у вопроса есть аудитория, голоса "за" и ответы, поэтому я воздержался от этого. Нетривиальность и интересность, в любом случае, понятия субъктивные и я бы рекомендовал дооформиить вопрос, как минимум для того, чтобы была возможность поиска решения для подобных задач

Comment: @Harry закрывать вопрос надо не как "необходимо конкретизировать", а как учебное задание. Это же "сделайте домашку" фактически. Попыток решения в вопросе нет. Я вообще считаю, чтог закрытие **не по той** причине - зло.

Comment: @Зонтик В этом и суть данного вопроса, прочитай второй абзац.

Comment: @Зонтик отсутствие попыток решения - лучше чем белиберда для галочки

Comment: Стоило немного привлечь внимание к вопросу, как он уже получил 8 голосов (и 15 голосов ответ). Это, как мне кажется, и есть ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @Mikhailo по такой логике, например, это вот божественно-хороший вопрос ))) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16774

Comment: @Зонтик не будьте так категоричны к наличию решения. ТС математического вопроса подумал, пришел к некому выводу и свои умственные заключения написал в вопросе. Это не то же самое, что: "Вот задача, реши для меня". Я под ?учебными вопросами бывает спрашиваю если не попытку решения, то хотя бы направление мысли ТСа. Это нормально не иметь решения

Comment: @Зонтик Зато этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1506161/228791 ни у кого не вызывает возражений (и даже привел к ответу). Видимо, добавить код с решением на другом языке и просьбой перевести на нужный и есть тяжелый самостоятельный труд по решению задачи.

Comment: @Mikhailo "ни у кого не вызывает возражений" - поэтому его заминусовали до -5. А ответ - до -2. И наверняка на вопросе есть хоть один голос за закрытие

Comment: @Зонтик Заминусовали и закрыли - как говорят, "две большие разницы". За закрытие только два голоса, и один из них мой )) Кстати, прямо сейчас, и один голос был до меня. Так что он вряд ли ваш. Третий не повился. Так что вы лично за то, чтоб оставить вопрос, который идеально вписывается в причину "сделать задание", в отличие от обсуждавшегося здесь вопроса, который вы сочли именно таким. О чем я вам, собственно, и пишу. *закрывать вопрос надо не как "необходимо конкретизировать", а как учебное задание. Это же "сделайте домашку" фактически.* - ваши слова. А к этопу переводу у вас претензий нет.

Answer (score 3):

Я один из отдавших голос за закрытие. Мне было лень переходить на вторую страничку причин закрытия и вводить следующий текст:

**Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не соответствует тематике площадки (вопросы о программировании и системном администрировании). Хотя математика и смежна с программированием, но этот вопрос относится к её теоретической части (там где перебор "в лоб" нецелесообразен).**

Поэтому мое "необходимо конкретизировать" можно интерепретировать как:

**Необходимо конкретизировать, как именно вопрос относится к программированию.**

Comment: По теме: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8683/337980 для контекста.

Comment: Неужели математика в программировании только для перебора? :)

Comment: @AntonMenshov хорошая справка! Лично мне не нравится **захламление ruSO чисто теоретическими ребусами**, вопросами и упражнениями на логику, типа о взвешивании 12 монет, привередливых принцессах, количестве пианистов в Чикаго, поиске анаграмм и формул составления числа 2023 из простых чисел, доказательстве что между 888888 и 8888888 не менее НН простых чисел из цифр от 1 до 7, и прочее прочее.

Comment: Зря выделили жирным так много слов, достаточно было "мне не нравится" :)

Comment: @Mikhailo спасибо что обратили внимание, поправил )

Comment: а мы кстати с вами уже [обсуждали похожую тему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10994/337980), хотя там более специфично для численных методов, что, на мой взгляд, легче "привязывается к программированию" (безотносительно моего отношения, нужно это или нет).

Comment: @AntonMenshov раз уж у нас тут комментарии "по касательной", то вот, на мой взгляд, хороший вопрос, у которого есть практические применения, которому не хватает плюсов - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504743

Comment: По-моему лучше не лениться =).

Answer (score -4):

Вопрос действительно был закрыт не по той причине. Его следует закрыть, но по **причине совершенно другой**:

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Почему? Взгляните-ка ещё разок на текст вопроса:

> Задача: найдите минимальное N такое, что если из чисел 1,2,3...,N убрать любые 1000 чисел, то из оставшихся можно выбрать ровно 1000 чисел с суммой N.

> Сначала хотела написать код, чтобы получить ответ, но поняла, что не представляю, как он должен выглядеть в данной ситуации.
> Вручную сделала грубую оценку, получила что это число должно быть чуть больше миллиона, но не знаю, какое это число и не знаю, как доказать, что оно наименьшее.
> Заранее спасибо

Это явно задание **без попыток решения**. Вернее, попытки-то может и были, но **в вопросе их нет.**

#### Почему вопрос закрыли не по той причине?

Подозреваю, что во всём виноват *"стадный инстинкт"*: *"если кто-то проголосовал за закрытие по этой причине, то и я проголосую"* - вот что думали закрывающие.
Так делать не стоит, ведь первый проголосовавший человек мог ошибиться (он в данном случае и ошибся).

Закрытие вопросов не по той причине - **большая проблема**, ведь тогда закрытие **теряет смыл** и **даже вредит**. Такое закрытие **не поможет ни автору** исправить вопрос, **ни другим участникам**. Подробней, зачем нужно закрытие, [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2).

Comment: На самом деле, большая проблема в другом. А именно, в допуске к принятию решений людей, которые не обладают достаточными знаниями

Comment: @avp и ответственностью в принятии решений.